# Avoid loading main viewcontroller on receive of push notification ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I am using this below code on receive of push notification to show my `viewcontroller`. It is working fine but it first load the main `viewcontroller` and then notification `viewcontroller`. So every time user gets notification they see two `viewcontrollers` loading first the main and then notification `controller`.

How can i avoid this? From UI perspective it does not look good to load two view controllers.

```
UIViewController *main=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];            
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];
self.window.rootViewController =nil;
UIViewController *destCon = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RelNoti"];
UINavigationController *desNevCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:destCon];                       
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window.rootViewController  presentViewController:desNevCont animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the rootViewController of your app at the time of detecting push notification like below and avoid the transition between views:

```
UIViewController *destCon = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RelNoti"];
UINavigationController *desNevCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:destCon];


self.window.rootViewController = desNevCont;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

From your below code, it seems that you are assigning `mainViewController` as your `rootViewController` and then presenting the `notificationViewController` above it, which is what is creating transition of two views. So, simply limit your code with the above code.

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController; // You are doing it here
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window.rootViewController  presentViewController:desNevCont animated:YES completion:nil]; // presenting here
```

Answer (score 0):

Set animated to NO in this line,

```
[self.window.rootViewController  presentViewController:desNevCont animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: @RichieRich no problem :). I recommend using Rumin's answer though as it would be more efficient.